# How can I duplicate files on a SFTP server using JSch?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I faced problem to copy(duplicate) a file from one SFTP folder to another one on the same server.

So, question: Is there a some effective method to do it remotely (i.e. without copying a data to client and vice-versa)?

I am using Java with the [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SFTP one possibly can execute `! ...` which is execute local command.

```
! cp a.txt a-backup.txt
```

As JSch also can give an SSH connection, even the exclamation sign is moot.
For code you might find some starting point in the [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/). The Exec sample should do.

Comment: Note that we need a remote command, not a local one, thus the first half of your answer is not really relevant here. (The second half still works, thus still +1.) [Ankaŭ, saluton!]

Comment: Hi Joop,
I've implemented as you suggested - all works Ok.
Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to upvote your post, but anyway, thank you :)

@Paŭlo Ebermann - All post has a useful info :)

Comment: @Oleksandr_DJ: If you think the answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted (using the green checkmark icon beside the answer).

Answer (score 2):

The SFTP protocol itself does only support data transfer between client and server, not on the server itself.

You can use other parts of the underlying SSH protocol (and JSch's implementation therof) to execute a command on the server, though. In this case, as mentioned by Joop, an [Exec channel](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html) is the right thing to use. You can use the same [Session](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html) you have used for your [ChannelSftp](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html) also for any number of other channels, e.g. for your exec channel. Just make sure to close any channels after use. (Have a look at the [Shell, Exec or Subsystem Channel](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsch/index.php?title=Shell,_Exec_or_Subsystem_Channel) page at the JSch wiki for some more info.

This will of course not work if the server doesn't support command execution, e.g. if it is configured to only support SFTP. Then your only solution is to download and re-upload this file.